# Custom Post Type children and grand-children in one list

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, get-posts, children

So, here is the story: i made a product catalogue with 3 custom post types:

```
 - Product
    - Filegroup (Child of Product)
        - File (Child of Filegroup)
```

When on product page it should show a list with the Filegroup title and the loose files under the correct Filegroup. But it shows the children at both parents

It's like this now:

```
- Filegroup 1
    - File 3 (child of Filegroup 2)
    - File 1 (child of Filegroup 1)
    - File 2 (child of Filegroup 1)

- Filegroup 2
    - File 3 (child of Filegroup 2)
    - File 1 (child of Filegroup 1)
    - File 2 (child of Filegroup 1)
```

And it needs to be:

```
- Filegroup 1
    - File 1 (child of Filegroup 1)
    - File 2 (child of Filegroup 1)

- Filegroup 2
    - File 3 (child of Filegroup 2)
```

My current script

```
<?php 
    $childargs = array(
    'post_type' => 'filegroup',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    );
    $child_posts = get_posts($childargs);

    foreach ($child_posts as $child_post){
    $parentid = $child_post->ID;
        ?>
            <ul>
                <li><strong><?php echo $child_post->post_title; ?></strong></li>
                    <?php
                        $childargs2 = array(
                        'post_type' => 'file',
                        'numberposts' => -1,
                        'post_parent' => '0'
                        );
                        $child_posts2 = get_posts($childargs2);

                        foreach ($child_posts2 as $child_post){
                        ?>
                            <li><?php echo $child_post->post_title; ?></li>
                        <?php
                        }
                    ?>
            </ul>

        <?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i lost track with all the crappy code, i decided to start all over :) And so i found the solution:

```
<?php
    // Define variables
    $post_type = 'file';
    $taxonomy = 'file-category';
    $taxonomy_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);

    global $current_page_id;
    $current_page_id = get_the_ID();

    // Start if
    if ($taxonomy_terms) {

        // Start Foreach
        foreach ($taxonomy_terms as $taxonomy_term) {

            // Start arguments for getting the posts and taxonomy
            $arguments = array(
                'post_type' => $post_type,
                "$taxonomy" => $taxonomy_term->slug,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'caller_get_posts' => 1,
                'post_parent' => 0,
            );
            // End arguments

            // Set query to null
            $new_query = null;

            // Start WP_Query
            $new_query = new WP_Query($arguments);

            // Start fetching posts if
            if($new_query->have_posts() ) {

                ?>
                <ul>
                <?php

                    echo '<li><strong>' . $taxonomy_term->name . '</strong></li>';

                    // Start while
                    while($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post();

                        // Get parent id
                        $parent_id = wpcf_pr_post_get_belongs(get_the_ID(), 'product');

                        // Start if $parent_id and $current page id are equal
                        if($parent_id == $current_page_id){

                            ?>

                            <li>

                                <a href="<?php echo types_render_field("file-uploads", array( "raw" => "true") ); ?>">
                                    <span><?php the_title(); ?></span><?php echo(types_render_field("lang", array())); ?>
                                </a>

                            </li>

                            <?php

                        // End if $parent_id and $current page id are equal
                        }

                    // End while
                    endwhile;

                ?>
                </ul>
                <?php
            // End fetching if
            }

        // End foreach
        }

    // End if   
    }
?>
```